# Is there a way to make a sqrt function without using Math.sqrt ()and without loops?

Tags: java, recursion, jgrasp

I'm trying to make program that uses recursive for a college homework but teacher does not want me to use loops for the problems but this is a jGRASP java program.
And this is the homework:[homework attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16zn8.jpg)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU4Dz.png)

I tried this code: [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FyNX.png)

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareRoot {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int x = scanner.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int y = scanner.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("" + powS(x));
   System.out.println("" + powNS(y));
 }
 
 public static int powS(int x) {
   int result = (2 * x) - 1;
   if (x == 0) {
     return 0;
   }
   return result + powS(x-1);
 }
 
 public static int powNS(int y) {
   int solution = (2 * y) - 1;
   if (y == 0) {
     return 0;
   }
   return solution + powS(y-1);
 }
}
```

And the square function worked but the only problem is that I can't figure out how to change the last method to make a square root function without loops(no while loops and no for loops)

I tried this code: [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoVyj.png)

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareRoot9 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int x = scanner.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int y = scanner.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("" + powS(x));
   System.out.println("" + powNS(y));
 }
 
 public static int powS(int x) {
   int result = 2 * (x-1);
   if (x == 0) {
     return 0;
   }
   return result * powS(x-1);
 }
 
 public static int powNS(int y) {
   int solution = 2 * (y-1);
   if (y == 0) {
     return 1;
   }
   if (y == 1) {
     return solution;
   }
   return solution / powNS(y-1);
 }
}
```

but there's an error

And then I tried this code: [my code]

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareRoot10 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int x = scanner.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int y = scanner.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("" + powS(x));
   System.out.println("" + powNS(y));
 }
 
 public static int powS(int x) {
   int result = (2 * x) - 1;
   if (x == 0) {
     return 0;
   }
   return result + powS(x-1);
 }
 
 public static int powNS(int y) {
   int solution = (2 / y) - 1;
   if (y == 0) {
     return 0;
   }
   return solution + powS(y-1);
 }
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZRQV.png) and it worked but the code didn't retrieve the answer I'm looking for and the code says I got 625 when I was looking for the square root of the number.

Does anyone know how to solve or change the last method so I can get the square root of a number for a jGRASP java program?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: David, I don't know how to put my code in the question here unlike other users do and my professor for Finger Lakes Community College always wants me to take a screenshot and submit the question here.

Comment: *"I don't know how to put my code in the question here"* - Text can be copied and pasted.  If the formatting is a struggle, the community can help with that because questions are publicly editable.  *"my professor [...] always wants me to take a screenshot and submit the question here"* - Your professor has misinformed you of how this community works.  Your professor is also encouraged to start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: David, I meant on my learning platform which is called Brightspace by "submit the question here" because it only relates to Brightspace

Comment: Your assignment **tells** you how to approach the solution. "Using Newton's method..." which it then explains in detail.  And then the assignment says "use recursion". It is all spelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make a sqrt function without using Math.sqrt ()and without loops?
> Yes.

You can use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) in combination with recursion.

Consider if you want to find the **sqrt(10)**.  Then the equation
**f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> - 10** will solve for **x** when **f(x) = 0**.

The first  derivative of **f(x)** is  **f'(x) = 2*x**.  So read the wiki page apply **x, f(x), and  f'(x)** as described.

- first do it in a loop to ensure you have the algorithm down.
- then do it recursively to fulfill the requirements.
- in both cases you should stop the iteration when **|x<sub>n+1</sub> - x<sub>n</sub>|** are within a reasonable tolerance.
- finally, you will want to use some variable in place of **10** in the above mentioned equations to take the sqrt root of any number.

Comment: You're of course correct, but the details (explanation of Newton's method, and instruction to use recursion) are written in the actual assignment text.  The OP appears to have not read it.